# Autopopulate Google Form fields based on answer from list

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

I have a google form that I am creating. I have a list of "companies" that the person can select from, but the user still needs to enter the address, state, city, zip, etc... I am looking for a way to have the list item selected (the company) autopopulate the other fields (address, state, city, zip... )

Is there a way to do this in Google Forms? I have looked all over and haven't found a tutorial or hint at how to make this happen.

I'd like to pull the data from another spreadsheet, JSON, string data... etc...

Comment: I almost think this is not possible... currently...

Answer (score 0):

If you create the form via Google [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/) or HTML Service, you might be able to do something similar. In UiApp, the [ListBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box) invokes an [ChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#addChangeHandler(Handler)).

Using the Google Form API will not yield what you want as there are no selection listeners before submitting the form currently.